# Sybase equivalent in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sybase

I am doing a change of code from Sybase to Oracle.
I have problem in converting the below query to oracle.

```
Select Custodian_addr,convert(datetime,dateadd(ss,CreateDT,"01/01/1970")
```

Here `CreateDT` is the column name whose value for instance is `1015015173`
The result for date conversion (for this example)is March 1 2002 8:39 PM GMT

I researched and found an oracle alternative which results in error

```
Select Custodian_addr,to_char(CreateDT,"SS")
```

I am getting a query error in Oracle.I am not able to identify whats wrong. Since I am executing this in Perl [`"`] has to escaped or what might be the issue? Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'some address' as custodian_addr, 
  date '1970-01-01' + 1015015173/86400 as create_dt
 from dual
/

CUSTODIAN_AD CREATE_DT
------------ -------------------
some address 2002-03-01 20:39:33
```

Oracle date arithmetic is pretty simple -- adding 1 to a date increments it by 1 day.  So since that number is seconds, dividing it by 86400 (60*60*24) casts that number as a number of days (and fractions thereof).

Comment: @Peter.Is there any alternative of using to_char for this.

Comment: @peter  1015015173 ----Can this be set as the column name  date '1970-01-01' +field_name/864000)...will this work..??

Comment: Yes - I just used your value for example's sake.

Comment: SQL> select date '1970-01-01' + 1015015173/86400 from dual;

DATE'1970
---------
01-MAR-02
I am not getting the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get?

Your TO_CHAR function should not use double quotes. It needs to be

```
TO_CHAR(CreateDT,'SS')
```

If you put something in double quotes in Oracle, it's interpreted as an identifier, not a string constant.